# How to get list of paired bluetooth devices on Windows 10 Universal Application

Tags: c#, bluetooth, win-universal-app

I was looking how to get list of paired bluetooth devices in Windows 10 Universal Application and didn't found anything. There were a lot of info how to do it on Windows 8.1 application, but none of the solutions work for Windows 10 Universal App.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found the answer by myself. In UWA it is very easy to get paired bluetooth devices. Here is the code snippet:

```
var selector = BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);
```